# Match if the line has two or more of the same capitalized word

Tags: regex

Basically I want to match this:

> **So this. So that.** [this should match]
>
> Yes this. No that. [this shouldn't match]

I thought this would work:

```
(\b(\w+)\1\b.*){2,}
```

But right now, it's matching the second line too: https://regexr.com/5jhag

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: You may use `\b([A-Z]\w*)\b.*\b\1\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Match if the line has two or more of the same capitalized word

As you want to match capitalized words only a `\w` is not right because it matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters. Also using `\1` just after the capture group means consecutive repeats only. Finally `\b` is also required around matches.

You may use this regex:

```
\b([A-Z]\w*)\b.*\b\1\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JuAr1y/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `([A-Z]\w*)`: Match a capitalize word that start with uppercase letter followed by 0 or more of any word characters
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `\b\1\b`: Match same word as what we captured in group #1 surrounded with word boundaries

Answer (score 1):

`(\b(\w+)\1\b.*){2,}` is  a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). `\1` is a backreference that references the value of the group it is defined in and it is *always* assigned an *empty string*, at each iteration. Note: if you were to test with PCRE engine, there would be no match, see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/34jTUI/1), because `\1` is not empty, it is null and there is no match.

Your regex matches `Yes this. No that.` because the current expression **is equal to `(\b(\w+)\b.*){2,}`** and matches any word, then any text, two times or more.

Use

```js
.*\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\b.*\b\1\b.*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DnBVAH/1).

**Unicode version**:

```js
.*\b(\p{Lu}\p{L}+)\b.*\b\1\b.*
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/DnBVAH/2).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```